# Galaxy S2, Hangouts app deletes incoming text messages

Tags: sms, google-hangouts

Incoming SMS messages tend to get deleted immediately on my Galaxy S2. The original messages app does not cause any issues, but if I turn on hangouts it goes nits.

Edit: were talking about an unrooted galaxy s2 with the latest Samsung firmware. If I disable hangout sms feature everything is fine.  Funny thing there was a big period of time when hangouts worked flawlessly.  I guess the desire is to use hangouts for sms if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There could possibly be a bug which is causing the app to Delete the latest incoming messages .

1. Un-install the application.
2. Power off and wait for 2-3mins
3. Switch ON the device and install the App from the Play store
4. Check for and install the latest updates for Hangouts from the play
   store

Always keep your applications up to date in order to avoid some bugs like this in the future

Comment: This cannot possibly work. Hangouts cannot be uninstalled and I tried removing updates.  It's always kept up to date.  Oh well was hoping someone knew of a workaround.

Comment: @DmitriyLikhten to be fair it can be uninstalled on many devices. What version of Android are you on? Have you rooted the device? Are you running a custom ROM?

Comment: @DmitriyLikhten if you cannot un-install the software then at least go for disable it .By this you won't have to update the application and it won't bother you for good